# How to make the API call to wait until we get required data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, redux, async-await

I am using React Native and Redux. In initial state of Redux `emailExists` is set to `null`:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  // ...
  emailExists: null,
};
```

when registering user. First, I check if user already exists by sending a request to server and if user already exists, I show a toast.

```
const registerUser = (values, actions) => {
  checkEmail(values.userEmail);   // takes time to get result of `emailExists`
  
  if (emailExists) {            // `emailExists` is now `null` couldn't wait for response
     toastRef.current.show("Email already exists!");
     return;
  }
}
```

`checkEmail` code look like this:

```
function checkEmail(data) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return api_request
      .post("register/check/email", { email: data })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(emailExists(res.data.exists));
        dispatch(authError("Email already exists"));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`err`, err);
      });
  };
}
```

aftering dispatching `dispatch(emailExists(res.data.exists));`, the `emailExists` will be either `true` or `false`, but the problem is that since request takes time to get data from server, at first load of application `emailExists` is always set to `null`. Which means below condition will always be false in first load:

```
if (emailExists) {
   toastRef.current.show("Email already exists!");
   return;
}
```

```
function emailExists(payload){
  return {
    type: userConstants.EMAIL_EXISTS, 
    emailExists: payload
  }
}
```

How do I resolve this issue?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify functions like this to get the expected result.

```
function checkEmail(data,callback) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return api_request
      .post("register/check/email", { email: data })
      .then((res) => {
       // dispatch(emailExists(res.data.exists)); // You don't need this redux approach now because it will take time and will give you the same error
        dispatch(authError("Email already exists"));
        callback && callback(res.data.exists) // I am assuming here you got the response that email alreay exists and its value is true.
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`err`, err);
      });
  };
}
```

Now get the callback when the API request is done and you get the response.

```
    const registerUser = (values, actions) => {

      const callback = (isEmailExists) => {
       //Here you will get the value of the checkemail API (true/false)
       //Now do any action in this block of functions
       if (isEmailExists) {    
        toastRef.current.show("Email already exists!");
        return;
        }
      }

      checkEmail(values.userEmail,callback);
      

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mantu's answer is one solution. I would prefer using async/await for this use case. `dispatch()` returns whatever the function returned by the action creator returns. So in this case you are returning a promise, meaning you can await your `dispatch(checkEmail(values.userEmail))` call.

You will need to return whether the email exists from the promise, otherwise even if you weait for your checkEmail action to complete, the emailExists will not be up to date when you access it (since using useSelector will have to rerender the component to reflect the updates in the store).

```
const registerUser = async (values, actions) => {
  const emailExists = await checkEmail(values.userEmail);
  
  if (emailExists) {
     toastRef.current.show("Email already exists!");
     return;
  }
}
```

```
function checkEmail(data) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return api_request
      .post("register/check/email", { email: data })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(emailExists(res.data.exists));
        dispatch(authError("Email already exists"));
        return res.data.exists;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`err`, err);
      });
  };
}
```

If you don't want to return the property from the promise, you will need to get the value from the store synchronously via store.getState():

```
const registerUser = async (values, actions) => {
  await checkEmail(values.userEmail);
  const emailExists = selectEmailExists(store.getState());
  if (emailExists) {
     toastRef.current.show("Email already exists!");
     return;
  }
}
```